# Supporting or Not Supporting a Hypothesis

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I want to know if there is an appropriate one word antonym to "support" that I can use in the following context:

*I collected the data and it did not support my hypothesis.*

I considered using "it dismissed my hypothesis," but I'm looking for a better option. Dismissed seems to imply that my hypothesis was frivolous.

Comment: "Contradicted", perhaps?

Comment: Negated, disproved?

Comment: "Invalidated" is another possibility.

Comment: Rejected is a good candidate, although the data don’t do the rejecting. The researcher uses the data to support or reject a hypothesis using a statistical test of some kind or judgment.

Comment: "Undermined" is also possible in the case of your example. However there is a difference between a collection of data which fails to support a hypothesis and one which suggests strongly that it is not true, "undermined" is an expression of the latter..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Undermined, challenged, and invalidated are some good verbs to use when data is in opposition to the researcher's hypothesis.

Comment: These have already been suggested, and an answer should attribute (and give a linked and attributed supporting reference). However, as OP didn't do basic research which would have turned up all these words, the question should be closed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't know who OP is but I answered my own question. I don't see a close button anywhere either, so I don't really understand what you want me to do.

Comment: OP is the original poster (you in this case); can't you 'delete'? Googling "support" + "antonym" quickly gives these answers and many more. Which is probably why most gave them in 'comments', though close-voting for lack of research shown in the question is correct.